# Flutter low quality blured widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-layout, flutter-design

I have the following design for a background of an app and would like to implement it in Flutter:
[image: Background]

My question is now what is the best way to implement it. Because I have tried to implement it with a BackdropFilter, but then it looks in the app itself not so good and more like poor quality:

[image: Actual app]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're searching for is a [RadialGradient](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/RadialGradient-class.html).
Here's how you use it with a `Container`'s `BoxDecoration` :

```
Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient:  RadialGradient(
                colors: [
                  Colors.red,
                  Colors.blue,
                ],
              )
            )
```